# Most recent cost value as of date by item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to generate item cost history. Items have cost values that change over time. For easier reporting, I'm trying to generate output that has a cost value by item by week ending date.  What I'm fighting with is outputting the most recent item cost value for a given week end date, since most of the time the eff_dt dates will not line up with a week ending date (`tran_end_dt`).

I have the following data (simplified):

```
create table Item( item_id int )

insert into Item values(1),(2),(3)

create table DatesTable( tran_end_dt date )

insert into DatesTable values('2014-01-04'),('2014-01-11'),('2014-01-18'),('2014-01-25')

create table ItemCostHist ( item_id int, eff_dt date, item_cost int )

insert into ItemCostHist values(1,'2014-01-01',1),(1,'2014-01-19',2),(2,'2014-01-05',1),(2,'2014-01-17',2),(3,'2014-01-01',1),(3,'2014-01-08',2),(3,'2014-01-22',3)
```

This should give:

Item

```
item_id
1
2
3
```

DatesTable (Looking at End week/Saturdays only)

```
tran_end_dt
2014-01-04
2014-01-11
2014-01-18
2014-01-25
```

ItemCostHist

```
item_id eff_dt  item_cost
1   2014-01-01  1
1   2014-01-19  2
2   2014-01-04  1
2   2014-01-17  2
3   2014-01-01  1
3   2014-01-08  2
3   2014-01-22  3
```

For the sake of keeping the post clean, I won't clutter it with a bunch of failed SQL attempts.  What I've been trying to do, is cross join `Item` and `DatesTable` as an inline view to give each week ending date and item_id, and then join this set against the `ItemCostHist` data. I keep running into trouble when attempting to get the `item_cost` value with an `eff_dt` that is less than or equal to the `tran_end_dt`.

*I could solve this iteratively, but I'd like advice or examples on how to solve this with a set based approach.*

Desired output:

```
Item    tran_end_dt Item Cost
1   2014-01-04  1
1   2014-01-11  1
1   2014-01-18  1
1   2014-01-25  2
2   2014-01-04  1
2   2014-01-11  2
2   2014-01-18  2
2   2014-01-25  2
3   2014-01-04  1
3   2014-01-11  2
3   2014-01-18  2
3   2014-01-25  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but this gets me the result I want.

```
select item_id
       , tran_end_dt
       , cost
from
(select distinct item_id, tran_end_dt from item cross join datestable) a
outer apply (select top 1 item_cost as cost 
                from itemcosthist ich 
                   where ich.eff_dt <= a.tran_end_dt 
                     and ich.item_id = a.item_id 
                      order by eff_dt desc) b
order by item_id, tran_end_dt, cost
```

Answer (score 0):

See this I think I have here what you are looking , but not too sure why you would like to do so anyway heres my solution

```
SELECT item_id
       ,eff_dt
       ,item_cost
FROM ItemCostHist
UNION 
SELECT item_id
       ,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, eff_dt)), eff_dt) [WeekEnd]
       ,item_cost
FROM ItemCostHist
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ item_id ║   eff_dt   ║ item_cost ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║       1 ║ 2014-01-01 ║         1 ║
║       1 ║ 2014-01-04 ║         1 ║
║       1 ║ 2014-01-19 ║         2 ║
║       1 ║ 2014-01-25 ║         2 ║
║       2 ║ 2014-01-04 ║         1 ║
║       2 ║ 2014-01-17 ║         2 ║
║       2 ║ 2014-01-18 ║         2 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-01 ║         1 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-04 ║         1 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-08 ║         2 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-11 ║         2 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-22 ║         3 ║
║       3 ║ 2014-01-25 ║         3 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

[M. Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565867/173497) has the key; you need a way to convert a date to a week-ending date. I don't trust the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.110).aspx) system function tho, because it's *possible* for it to give different values based on a [system setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598(v=sql.110).aspx).

Here's an example with similar code tho:

```
SELECT  x.Date,
        WeekDate = DATEADD(day, 6, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, x.Date), 0))
FROM (  SELECT Date = '1904-02-13'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '1904-02-14'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '1904-02-15'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '1960-08-12'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2013-06-04'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2014-01-21'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2014-01-22'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2014-01-23'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2014-01-26'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Date = '2014-01-27'
    ) x
ORDER BY Date;

--Date       WeekDate
------------ -----------------------
--1904-02-13 1904-02-14 00:00:00.000
--1904-02-14 1904-02-21 00:00:00.000
--1904-02-15 1904-02-21 00:00:00.000
--1960-08-12 1960-08-14 00:00:00.000
--2013-06-04 2013-06-09 00:00:00.000
--2014-01-21 2014-01-26 00:00:00.000
--2014-01-22 2014-01-26 00:00:00.000
--2014-01-23 2014-01-26 00:00:00.000
--2014-01-26 2014-02-02 00:00:00.000
--2014-01-27 2014-02-02 00:00:00.000

--(10 row(s) affected)
```